# AngularJS custom filter for two columns

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i have a select-box with option1 and option2;
i have a table with column1,  column2,  column3,  column4. Column2 and column3 are numeric fields.

1) i want that i selected option1 in select-box, the table show the rows that all fileld in column2 are >0 and all fields of column3 are == 0

2)  i want that i selected option2 in select-box, the table show the rows that all fileld in column2 are ==0 and all fields of column3 are > 0

example

```
select class="form-control" name="optionsSelect" ng-model="ctrl.table.filterParams.optionSelect" 
        ng-options="option for option in ctrl.ctx.option">
</select>

<div class="bt-table">
    <table class="table table-striped" ng-table="ctrl.tableParams" id="exampleTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="item in items"><p ng-bind-html="item"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.table.data">
          <td><a>{{item.column1}}</a></td>
          <td>{{item.column2}}</td>
          <td>{{item.column3}}</td>
          <td>{{item.column4}}</td>
           <td>{{item.column5| date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</td>
          <td>{{item.column6| currency : "" | currencyformat }}</td>
         </span></td>

          <td>{{item.column7}}</td>
          <td>                
            {{item.column8}}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Can you post a working jsfiddle, with your controller code?

Answer (score 1):

Using angular "filter" filter.

**Put this in your controller**

```
ctrl.filterCriteria = function (item) {
    if (ctrl.table.filterParams.optionSelect == option1) {
        return item.column2 > 0 && item.column3 == 0;
    } else if (ctrl.table.filterParams.optionSelect == option2) {
        return item.column2 == 0 && item.column3 > 0
    } else {
        // Display all items
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Change this in Template:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ctrl.table.data | filter:ctrl.filterCriteria">
```

Something like this should work, I couldn't test it because I don't have test data. If you have any problems with this please add a jsfiddle and I'll have a look at it.